# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'title'

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Code:

```
class trafikformu(db.Model):

    title = db.StringProperty()

class QueryHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self,id):
        v = form.get_by_id(int(id))
        self.response.out.write(v.title) # AttributeError
```

The line `self.response.out.write(v.title)` gives this error: `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'title'`.

How can i solve this problem?

Comment: Everytime you see `'NoneType'` in a Python error message it is because you have done `None.<something>`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The function `form.get_by_id(int(id))` returned `None` for the given `id`, so `v` has no attribute `title` since it is `None`.

Comment: And `v` is none because no entity with that ID exists in the datastore.